# Error saving meeting data: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: node.js, angularjs, oracle, express

while parsing the data from server.js file into the db i am getting Error saving meeting data: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data this error.
in firefox console i have get this output after console log the data before requesting

```
type hereconst express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const app = express();
const port = 3000; // Adjust the port as needed

// Database connection details (replace with your actual credentials)
const dbConfig = {
  user: 'mana0809',
  password: 'mana0809',
  connectString:"(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST   = exanode-x8m-ijztf-scan.allexadbclients.macomspokevcn.oraclevcn.com)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=MCPDB.allexadbclients.macomspokevcn.oraclevcn.com)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))))"
  
};

// Connect to Oracle database using connection pool
oracledb.createPool(dbConfig, (err, pool) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to Oracle database:', err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit on error
  }

  console.log('Connected to Oracle database');

  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // API endpoint to handle incoming meeting data from Angular
  app.post('/api/save-meeting', async (req, res) => {
    const meetingData = req.body;
    console.log('Received data:', req.body);

    try {
      const connection = await pool.getConnection();
      const sql = `
        INSERT INTO MEETING (
          name, state, day, attendees, performer_name, team_size,
          department, product_name, meeting_subject, status
        ) VALUES (
          :name, :state, :day, :attendees, :performerName, :teamSize,
          :department, :productName, :meetingSubject, :status
        )
      `;
      console.log('connection:',sql);

      const binds = {
        name: meetingData.Name,
        state: meetingData.state,
        day: meetingData.day, // Adjust data type if needed (e.g., DATE)
        attendees: meetingData.Attendees,
        performerName: meetingData.performerName,
        teamSize: meetingData.TeamSize,
        department: meetingData.department,
        productName: meetingData.Product_Name,
        meetingSubject: meetingData.meetingsubject,
        status: meetingData.Status
      };
      console.log(binds);

      const result = await connection.execute(sql, binds);

      if (result.rowsAffected === 1) {
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Meeting data saved successfully' });
      } else {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error saving meeting data' });
      }

      await connection.close(); // Release the connection back to the pool
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving meeting data:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error saving meeting data' });
    }
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
  });
});
```

type here this is my backend code from where i can inserting a data into the my table